# IsNothing not working on empty value in report builder

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, reportbuilder3.0

I have an expression in a table that checks if there was a return value.

If the query returns empty or `null` I want to set the value to *0*.

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!DndCount.Value),0,Fields!DndCount.Value)
```

But if the query returns empty `IsNothing()` does not work.

Comment: What's the datatype of `DndCount`? Is it a string? For a count field I would expect it to be an int, which doesn't have a concept of *empty*; it's either `NULL` or it isn't.

Comment: the datatype is int, in some case the query returns zero lines, in this case how can I set the value to "0".

Comment: Is this expression being used in a Detail row or in a Header/Footer row?

Comment: You might find this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319220/ssrs-no-data-in-report

Answer (score 3):

I have tried this code and it worked for me.

```
IIF(Sum(Fields!DndCount.Value)Is Nothing, "0", Sum(Fields!DndCount.Value))
```

Comment: You sir, saved the day! Thank you.

Comment: Great suggestion, but it still doesn't work on my stupid version of Report Builder. I hate MS's old garbage pre-Nadella.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution to avoid using expressions, change the cell format to `#,##0` in properties. Easier then to pair it up with count or sum.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=IIF(Fields!DndCount.Value=0 OR 
IsNothing(Fields!DndCount.Value)=0 OR
Fields!DndCount.Value="null",0,Fields!DndCount.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `IsNothing` will return a `True` or `False` value you need to set your expression as:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Field1) = True, 0, Field2)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use the `IsMissing` expression of the field,

like this:

```
=IIF(Fields!Accounting_Amount.IsMissing, 0, Fields!Accounting_Amount.Value)
```