# embedded IIF States in SSRS

Tags: vba, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, iif

Thank you for taking your time to help me today. I am trying to use multiple if statements to control what value is displayed depending on whether each statement is true. So right now I have this below which is essentially:

```
IIF(expression = NULL
, CompanyAddress
, IIF(Expression='TX'
    , IIF(BOOL=TRUE
        ,CompanyAddress
        , SWITCH(DEALER ADDRESSES))
    ,CompanyAddress)
)
```

I have tested each individual IIF statements separately and I get the outcomes which I expect. Currently in the first IIF statement and the Expression = NULL is TRUE , It just outputs #Error and not the "Nothin" OR in my real case Company Address. But if Expression = NULL is FAlSE, I do get the correct output of either the companyAddress or the Dealer.

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!CoOppId.Value)
,("nothin")
, (IIF(Fields!Addr1.Value.Contains("TX")
    , IIF(Fields!UDFCustProv.Value = 1
        , Fields!Addr0.Value
        , Switch(
            Fields!UDFMake.Value.Contains("Chevy")
            , "Knapp Chevrolet" + chr(10) + "PO box " + chr(10) + "Houston TX 77210"
            , Fields!UDFMake.Value.contains("Ford") 
            , "Sterling McCall Ford" + chr(10) + "6445 Southwest Freeway" + chr(10) + "Houston TX 77074"
            , Fields!UDFMake.Value.contains("International")
            , "Pliler International" + chr(10) + "2016 S. Eastman Rd" + chr(10) + "Longview TX 75602"
            , Fields!UDFMake.Value.contains("Freightliner")
            , "Houston Freightliner, Inc" + chr(10) +"9550 North Loop East" + chr(10) + "Houston TX 77029"
            , Fields!UDFMake.Value.contains("RAM")
            , "Max Haik Dodge Chrysler Jeep" +chr(10)+ "11000 I-45 North Freeway" + chr(10) + "Houston TX 77037")),Fields!Addr0.Value)))
```

Comment: Give this answer a try: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511151/isnothing-not-working-on-empty-value-in-report-builder)

Comment: No luck on that thread

Comment: You said the ELSE condition on the main IIF works fine, so can you strip this down to just the single top level IIF and tell us if that still generates an error? actually I see now that you said you did already confirm that this works. Next question, in the case that CoOppId is NULL, are the other fields in that row NULL as well?

Comment: No, I am simply checking to see if this field is null and then displaying the fields which should be populated if CoOppId is Null.

Comment: I think that Daniel has a point. When CoOppId is Null, at least another one field in your expression is null and that is the reason for the #Error. Try using `COALESCE(fieldname,'')`  in your SQL code for the rest of the string fields or `COALESCE(fieldname,0)` for numeric fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Daniel, the error is most likely being produce by the `Fields!UDFMake.Value.Contains` when the value is null, as IIF does not short-circuit.
Alternatively to the good options that @Daniel mentioned you can replace the contains method by the function InStr as:

```
... , Switch(
            InStr(Fields!UDFMake.Value,"Chevy") > 0
            , "Knapp Chevrolet" + chr(10) + "PO box " + chr(10) + "Houston TX 77210" ...
```

this will not produce an error even when the value of the field is Null.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a guess that when your CoOppId value is NULL, that your other fields in that row are also NULL.  Because IIF does not utilize short circuit logic (it always evaluates both sides of the IIF), you are trying to evaluate the expression "NULL.Contains("TX")" and that will generate an #ERROR because NULL is not a string and cannot be operated on with the CONTAINS function.

There are two workarounds available for this scenario, neither of them particularly nice in my opinion, however:

1) Use nested IIFs to ensure that nothing is ever invalid.

```
IIF(expression is NULL 
, CompanyAddress
, IIF(**IIF(expression is NULL, "", expression)** ='TX'
    , IIF(BOOL=TRUE
        ,CompanyAddress
        , SWITCH(DEALER ADDRESSES))
    ,CompanyAddress)
)
```

Look at the pseudo code above and notice the additional nested IIF around the expression that is using the CONTAINS functionality.  If CoOppId doesn't exist, it substitutes in an empty string for the CONTAINS check. Even though this branch never shows it's value for the null scenario, it will at least be valid now.

2) Create a code-behind function that actually does perform short circuit logic for you:

```
Public Function CheckForNull(ByVal CoOppId As String, ByVal Addr1 as String, ByVal UDFMake As String, ... all fields)
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(CoOppId) 
  Return "Nothing"
Else
  Return *** do your calculation with your fields here
End If
End Function
```

Which you utilize in your report like:

```
=Code.CheckForNull(values....)
```

I just roughly laid out how such a code behind function works, it's obviously not complete but should be enough to point you in the right direction.

Comment: This seems to be the right direction from my further research. I will attempt this and get back with you with my findings

Comment: Custom code would be a good workaround to avoid errors and also make your expression's easier to read

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your great response. It seems you had the right Idea, But Jayvee's answer was the solution that made my scenario work. If I could mark both as answers I would.