# How do I show a row in SSRS when no data is available?

Tags: reporting-services

My code in the first text box in a tablix row is as follows:

```
=IIF(CountRows("DataSet") = 0, "Row Label", (IIF(RowNumber("ThisTablix") = 1, "Row Label", "")))
```

My understanding of the logic is that:

1. If the number of rows returned in the data set "DataSet" is 0, then the row should appear with a text box that says "Row Label"
2. If data is available in "DataSet" then if this is the first row in the tablix, the textbox should say "Row Label".

However when I attempt to run the report without any data, the row does not seem to be appearing.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Where you getting your data from for the DataSet, do a row count. If it is zero insert a row. This should be the easiest way.

Comment: @Snowlocck that would be good but I'd also like to understand why the nested IIF above isn't working

Comment: I think it's because there are no rows so the code in the rows never gets generated. So this code doesn't run.

Answer (score 3):

I think your point 1 is incorrect.  If zero rows are returned, your textbox will never be evaluated.  Look for the [NoRowsMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/set-a-no-data-message-for-a-data-region-report-builder-and-ssrs) property, and set it.  Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319220/ssrs-no-data-in-report).